# Samsung Phone write protection

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, usb-debugging, file-transfer, copy-paste

I just bought a new Samsung Galaxy M11. I'm trying to transfer my files from my old phone to the new phone connected to a PC but it won't copy. I get the pop-up that says the internal storage is write protected. I have tried the developer options too by switching on and off the USB Debugging but it still doesn't work. I have searched the web but all I get is related to external storage or SD card. Is there anyway to remove the write protection on the internal storage?

Comment: check `mount` for `ro` flags